# com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jaxb/JaxbAnnotationModule is not assignable to com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/module

Tags: java, spring, maven, jboss

I have provided a JAR file to the client and then they put it in their server. Whenever they tried to start the JBoss server, this error occurs. But when we do a rollback, all is fine.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcZBb.png)

The JAR file I have provided was tested in my laptop using the java -jar (name).jar to make sure that my JAR is not encountering an error upon execution.

Comment: What container are you running in?

Comment: I can now successfully start the jboss server without any error. My jar file should not have a dependent library but need to declare the dependecies in module.xml.